# JPanel Paint method

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am trying to display a graph once the file has been chosen using the repaint method, It is not providing me with any errors but there is something I am doing wrong that it is not displaying the graph, I am new to the paint method so I think thats why its not working.

Code:

```
private final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    private final JTextArea listArea = new JTextArea();
    //private final JTextArea graphArea = new JTextArea();
```

Below is the JPanel I'm trying to output graph to:

```
private final JPanel graphArea = new JPanel();
    private final JButton read = new PosJButton("Read", 0);
    private final JButton breadth = new PosJButton("Breadth", 0);
    private final JButton depth = new PosJButton("Depth", 0);
```

My class for repainting the panel:

```
private class graphArea extends JPanel    {

        public graphArea()  {
            graphArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(255,255));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    }
    }

    //method creating a new gui
    public static void makeAndShowGUI() {
        graphGUI gGUI = new graphGUI();
        gGUI.showGUI();
    }

        //setting items for gui
yout);
            listArea.setRows(1);
);
            contentPane.add(buttonPanel);
            contentPane.add(graphArea);    




                                    newStation.addStation(name, posx, posy);
                                    System.out.println("Station test: " + name + " " + posx + " " + posy);
                                }
                                else if(type.equals("Connection:")){
                                    String statA = sc.next();
                                    String statB = sc.next();
                                    double dist = sc.nextDouble();



                                    newStation.addConnection(statA, statB, dist);
                                    System.out.println("Connection test: " + statA + " " + statB + " " + dist);
                                }
                            }
```

Here is where I am trying to repaint the jpanel graphArea:

```
graphArea.repaint();
                        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid file format", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }


        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all class names should start with an upper case character.

The size of your `GraphArea` (note the proper name) is (0, 0), so there is nothing to paint.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the panel. Then the layout manager can work properly.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: @codingmachine, Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a working example.